# adding profile pic,username on toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

How to include  user profile picture and username  on android toolbar as well as navigation drawer.So there will be just a navigation drawer and user name and user picture on the bar.please help.

Answer (score -2):

`Toolbar` is just a `ViewGroup`, you can customize is as much as you want. You can add any view into it.
You can customize your `NavigationDrawer` also as you wish.
Have a look on the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html
and
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
[In android app Toolbar.setTitle method has no effect – application name is shown as title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown)

Comment: @sanjeet--Thank you..can you please tell me how am i suppose to put a user profile image in a tool bar.

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534343/toolbar-image-centered
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486730/in-android-app-toolbar-settitle-method-has-no-effect-application-name-is-shown