# How to add image in toolbar

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-toolbar

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) example to create my app now i am trying to add image in my toolbar the but image is not displaying,i am trying to set my app logo,following is my code and toolbar xml can any one tell me what is mistake?

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle"
        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    private String chng;
    private Intent i;
    public SearchView searchView;
    public SearchManager searchManager;

    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Session Manager Class
    SessionManager session;

    private String id;
    private boolean b;
    private String rasa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
        System.out.println("MAIN ID : " + id);
       /* i=getIntent();
        chng=i.getStringExtra("Changes");*/

      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),chng,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout),mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
        displayView(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

This how my toolbar shows right now

[image]

Comment: @Blackbelt i am not talking about hamburger icon..i want image instead of title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

instead you can set your image as textview background. use `android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle".` and setTitle("") in your code.

your final toolbar will look like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle"
    local:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: i am saying to use image as your toolbar background

Comment: without using imageview how you gonna set the image??

Comment: i have setted your image as toolbar background...read answer then  try and then comment if not work

Comment: I used your method and set setTitle("") to the toolbar but i still get the name of my project in the title. I searched and removed it, now I am getting the package name in the title...

Comment: I was successful in removing the title by `app:title=" "`; notice the space

Answer (score 30):

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_blue"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_header_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/header_title" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can set Event of button also by this method...

```
 public static void showToolBar(Toolbar toolbar,
                                   final AppCompatActivity activity) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Drawable drawable = activity.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.mipmap.back_icon);
        drawable.setColorFilter(
                activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white),
                android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.color_blue));
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: getDrawable is deprecated as of API22

Comment: Having ImageView inside Toolbar is not allowed in version 28.

Comment: you can put any views @Kostadin

Answer (score 13):

Use the logo display on the action bar.

```
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: it can display in center of toolbar and title moved to right side

Comment: I am using this method, but the image (logo) is now in the center of toolbar and the title is gone. How can I move logo to the right (end), and title to the left (start)?

Answer (score 1):

It was mistake done by me,i was checking with custom toolbar xml,but i already have toolbar in my activity_main.xml..Hope my answer will help others too

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/MyToolBarStyle.Base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!-- activity view -->
        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- navigation drawer -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the image src attribute rather than setting the imageview background drawable.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/toolbartitle"
    />
```

Comment: Is your drawable a valid resource?

Comment: what do you mean valid resource?

Comment: Is it a PNG image which you can see when opened in the editor? Are you actually including the Toolbar within activity_main.xml?

Comment: yes it is png image..and see in my question and for more i already mentione the link of my example

Comment: Post activity_main.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93162/discussion-between-lakhan-and-fractalwrench).

Answer (score 0):

You missed to show the source

```
android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
```

if not working try adding some genuine width and height instead of wrap content

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Comment: i already tried with src no change with that..see my edited question for code now