# Android Profile image in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I put the profile image inside the default ActionBar?

My app, for while, is like the image bellow:

[image: Actions bar]

In the image above, the first Actionbar is the default and the second bar (with image and Profile's name) is the one I have created.

I would like to use the default ActionBar with image inside it, as shown in image bellow:

[image: ActionBar with image]

Maybe I need to create a custom Actionbar by myself, but if have a way to do with the default ActionBar, I will try.

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300978/how-to-add-image-in-toolbar) may this will help you.

Comment: As I thought... I have to create my own Action bar. The documentation of the Android Studio tells that, after 21th version, is not a best practice to insert name and icons on action bar, just one or another one, never both. Thanks for all and to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom action bar

**`actionbar.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="APP_Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add following lines in **`Activity.java`**

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

**OR**

You can use following code to set icon on action bar

```
setTitle("title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_icon);
```

**OR**

If you have constant logo then add following code in `manifest` file

**For single activity**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon" 
       android:label="title" />
```

**For all activities**

```
<application
    android:logo="@drawable/profile_icon">

    ...

</application>
```

Comment: how we can do it for kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collapsing toolbar as it will collapse and appear as a single action bar when collapsed. And when dragged down you'll get all the contents inside it.