# Android - Logo at header in Activity with Drawer Menu

Tags: android, header, navigation-drawer

[Android :Want to display logo at Header in activity and place menu at left of the header.
can someone help me on how  to proceed to implement it. Please refer attached screenshot. If any links will be helpful.

Thanks
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Kn8.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolbar image centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534343/toolbar-image-centered)

Comment: https://medium.com/@janishar.ali/navigation-drawer-android-example-8dfe38c66f59

Comment: Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it. You need to add android:layout_gravity="center" in child image view tag.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, How can i set image programatically ?

Comment: i did it through programatically

Comment: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ImageView img=toolbar.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.logo);